# быстрая сортировка массива на javascript

Tags: javascript, сортировка, ecmascript-6

Есть такой код:

```
export default class quickSort {
    constructor() {}

    private static partition(mas, l, r) {
        function swap(mas, a:any, b:any) {

            let tmp: any = mas[a];
            mas[a] = mas[b];
            mas[b] = tmp;

            return mas;
        }

        let pos = l-1;
        for (let i = l; i <= r; ++i) {
            if (mas[i] <= mas[r] )
                mas = swap(mas, ++pos, i);
        }

        return pos;
    }

    private quick_sort(mas, l, r) {
        if (l >= r) {
            return;
        }
        let pivot = quickSort.partition(mas,l,r);

        this.quick_sort(mas,l,pivot-1);
        this.quick_sort(mas,pivot+1,r);
    }

    getSorted(mas, l, r) {
        this.quick_sort(mas,l,r);
        return mas;
    }
}
```

но он сортирует простой числовой массив. Не важно, что это числа, важно, что он не вложенный. Я хочу написать метод, который будет сортировать по полю в массиве. Допустим по `id`

Comment: зачем...скажи зачем тут метка **быстрая** и что она должна значить?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это быстрая сортировка

Comment: где? не вижу..... даже **быстрая сортировка** тут зачем? что она дополняет, определяет? не ставь бесполезные метки если не знаешь о чем они и зачем нужны

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а, да. Раздельно метки написались. Не заметил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if (mas[i] <= mas[r] )

меняем на

> if (mas[i].id <= mas[r].id )

Comment: для каждого поля отдельный класс делать? :-)

Comment: @Grundy можно и `if (mas[i].["id"] <= mas[r].["id"] )`, так что все норм

Comment: @Nikolay, в таком виде еще не норм :-) `id` же все еще жестко забито :)

Comment: @Grundy передав в функцию нужную строку. Или можно по первому полю

Comment: @Nikolay, в какую из четырех функций передавать?

Comment: partition(mas, l, r, **sortBy = "id"**). И тогда if (mas[i].[sortBy] <= mas[r].[sortBy]). ну и затем     let pivot = quickSort.partition(mas,l,r, **"id"**);

Comment: @КириллМатасов и опять возвращаемся к тому. что в этом случае для каждого поля нужно отдельный класс

Comment: Зачем, это же JS. Он и так схавает))... Ай да, точки забыл постирать))

Comment: Да, класс приходится пересоздавать) но это поправимо. Мне требовалась работающая сейчас сортировка, а оптимизация уже после